# Find a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a set of vectors $\{u,v\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ that spans the solution set of the equations:

Vector $u = [\,]$, vector $v = [\,]$.

\begin{eqnarray}
w-x-2y-4z&=&0\\5w+2x+y+3z&=&0
\end{eqnarray}
I have attempted this problem several times. I put it in reduced form which is

$\begin{bmatrix}
1&&0&&-2&&-4\\0&&1&&\frac{11}{7}&&\frac{23}{7}
\end{bmatrix}$

I am mostly confused on how the variables correspond to the numbers. Then this leaves my answer at:

$$ u=[2,-11/7,1,0]\qquad v=[4,-23/7,0,1]$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the approach seems to be correct, there appear to be some errors in the row-reduction which should be as follows:

$\begin{bmatrix}
1&&-1&&-2&&-4\\5&&2&&1&&3
\end{bmatrix}$

Perform operation $-5R_1+R_2\Rightarrow R_2$ to get
$\begin{bmatrix}
1&&-1&&-2&&-4\\0&&7&&11&&23
\end{bmatrix}$

Perform operation $\frac{1}{7}R_2\Rightarrow R_2$ to get
$\begin{bmatrix}
1&&-1&&-2&&-4\\0&&1&&\frac{11}{7}&&\frac{23}{7}
\end{bmatrix}$

Perform operation $R_2+R_1\Rightarrow R_1$ to get
$\begin{bmatrix}
1&&0&&-\frac{3}{7}&&-\frac{5}{7}\\0&&1&&\frac{11}{7}&&\frac{23}{7}
\end{bmatrix}$

This will give

$$ u=\left[-\frac{3}{7},\frac{11}{7},1,0\right]\qquad v=\left[-\frac{5}{7},\frac{23}{7},0,1\right]$$

But if you wish to avoid fractions, you can use any constant multiple of these two vectors, such as

$$ u=\left[-3,11,7,0\right]\qquad v=\left[-5,23,0,7\right]$$

Comment: Oh, we have to change row one because there has to be a zero above the pivot in row two?

Comment: Yes, it should be in *reduced* row echelon form.

Answer (score 0):

Row reduction correspond to and can be directly applied to the *equations* themselves.

The system of equations is equivalent to the one you found at the end of row reduction (unless you miscalculated), 
$$\matrix{w-2y-4z&=&0\\x+\frac{11}7y+\frac{23}7z&=&0}$$
And, to find a solution, just rearrange them, and arbitrarily choose values for $y$ and $z$. (A standard choice is taking $y=1,z=0$ and $y=0,z=1$, but you're also free to take e.g. $y=7,z=0$ and $y=0,z=7$.)
$$\matrix{w&=&2y+4z\\x&=&-\frac{11}7y-\frac{23}7z}$$
This seems just coinciding with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

w- x- 2y+ 4z= 0 and 5w+ 2x+ y+ 3z= 0.  From the first equation we get w= x+ 2y- 4z.  Putting that into the second equation gives 5(x+ 2y- 4z)+ 2x+ y+ 3z= 7x+ 11y- 17z= 0 and from that, z= (7/17)x+ (11/17)y.  Putting that back into w= x+ 2y- 4z we get w= x+ 2y- (28/17)x- (44/17)y= (-11/17)x- (6/17)y.  So every vector in this space is of the form (w, x, y, z)= ((-11/17)x- (6/17)y, x, y, (7/17)x+ (11/17)y)= ((11/17)x, x, 0, (7/17)x)+ (-(6/17)y, 0, y, (11/17)y)= (11/17, 1, 0, 7/17)x+ (-6/17, 0, 1, 11/17)y.

So a basis is {((11/17, 1, 0, 7/17), (-6/17, 0, 1, 11/17)).  Of course we can multiply each of those by 17 without changing the space they span.  That would give as a basis {(11, 1, 0, 7), (-6, 0, 1, 11)}.

Comment: Can you please use mathjax? This is really difficult to read..